# Strip out phone number formatting on form submit?

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using the following jQuery code to format phone numbers entered into inputs in my HTML form...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".phone-mask").mask("(ZZZ) ZZZ-ZZZZ", {
                translation: {
                    Z: {
                        pattern: /[0-9]/,
                        optional: !0
                    }
                },
                placeholder: ""
            })
        });
```

I want it to follow the above format for users' inputs – (XXX) XXX-XXXX ... but I need the data formatted as XXXXXXXXXX when it's submitted.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: `$('.phone-mask').cleanVal()` See: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#getting-the-unmasked-typed-value

Comment: Add a submit handler to the form to first remove all non-digits: `$('#myform').submit(function(){ $('.phone-mask').val( $('.phone-mask').val().replace(/[\D]/, '') ) })`.